# Icons missing after upgrading from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: icons, 22.04

I have upgraded from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. While installing, my computer runs out of power and shut down. When the power is back, some of the icons are missing in the new 22.04 like below.

How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]